# Lua unicode, using string.sub() with two-byted chars

Tags: string, unicode, utf-8, lua, char

As example: I want remove the first 2 letters from the string "ПРИВЕТ" and "HELLO." one of these are containing only two-byted unicode symbols.

Trying to use string.sub("ПРИВЕТ") and string.sub("HELLO.")

Got "Р**ИВЕТ**" and "**LLO.**".

string.sub() removed 2 BYTES(not chars) from these strings. So i want to know how to get the removing of the **chars**

Something, like utf8.sub()

Comment: To remove first `N` chars in UTF-8 string: `str = str:gsub(".[\128-\191]*", "", N)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The key standard function for this task is `utf8.offset(s,n)`, which gives the position in bytes of the start of the n-th character of s.

So try this:

```
print(string.sub(s,utf8.offset(s,3),-1))
```

You can define `utf8.sub` as follows:

```
function utf8.sub(s,i,j)
    i=utf8.offset(s,i)
    j=utf8.offset(s,j+1)-1
    return string.sub(s,i,j)
end
```

(This code only works for positive `j`. See http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2014-04/msg00590.html for the general case.)

Answer (score 0):

There is https://github.com/Stepets/utf8.lua, a pure lua library, which expand standard function to support utf8 string.

Answer (score -1):

I found a simpler solution (the the solution using offset() didnt work for me for all cases):

```
function utf8.sub(s, i, j)
    return utf8.char(utf8.codepoint(s, i, j))
end
```